# How can I run PostgreSQL DB service under Local System account?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL DB in my application, I used to create special windows user account to run the DB service.

Now I need to run PostgreSQL service under Local System account! Is there a configuration in PostgreSQL to specify the user account which the service runs under?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Computer Management -> Services -> select the Postgres server service -> right click -> Properties -> check the Log on tab, just like any other Windows service.

(Might be a bit off with the naming, I don't have access to a Windows machine at home, but I'm sure you can improvise.)

Answer (score 2):

Download the zip archived binaries from PostgreSQL site. Extract the contents. Create a folder, say 'data', for storing the db files etc. Open Windows Advanced System Configuration -> Environment Variables.

Create a new System Variable called PGDATA and set its value to the complete path of data folder, as in - 'C:\PostgreSQL\data'(without the single quotes).

Next in Path variable include the complete path to bin folder, as in - 'C:\PostgreSQL\bin;....' .

Once done, do the following...

1. Open command prompt(as Admin in Vista and Win 7 systems). Type: 'initdb' and press Enter. This will do the initial setup.
2. In the same command prompt window, type in: 'pg_ctl register -N PostgreSQL -U LocalSystem' and press enter.
   Open run and type services.msc and check if the process 'PostgreSQL' has been created and that you can actually start it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you need to do anything special to run this under a local system account.  We use PostgreSQL databases here and we install them on local system accounts all the time.  I have never seen a configuration setting in the installation that allows you to indicate a system account for the service.